# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is stack trace exception:

```
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 64
```

I rebase application in laravel on over server. And get this message but token exist in form and passed to backend in post request.

Image:

[image: Console Image]

I think this session but I don't recive php error in logs server and don't receive notice and warning.

**P.S.**: This laravel 5

Comment: Double check your session config. Maybe some settings were changed? If the `.env` file got changed or removed somehow, that may be causing the error. You could also try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @PatrickStephan fanks I'm try. file .env not exist I pull from git repository.

Comment: If you are using the `file` sessions option, make sure that `/storage/framework/sessions` exists or if you are using database sessions, the database table exists (though that should error out in other areas if that is the case, I imagine)

Comment: @JoshJanusch fanks directory `/storage/framework/sessions` exists but session do not save in this directory. I fix the issuess, set database storage and create table by migration in console artisan. And it's work. But I don't understand way not work file option, i have right permission and php save file possible.

Comment: You're sure the permissions are correct and that the user running that PHP process can write to the sessions directory?

Comment: @JoshJanusch Yes I sure becase PHP save to cache, and user and group www-data:www-data and permission by mask 0775... Mda... Now I'm not sure )). Tomorrow I recheck permission.